# Как сделать чтоб по нажатию левой кнопки мыши, скрипт не срабатывал, когда курсор на кнопке?(Unity2d)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать чтоб по нажатию левой кнопки мыши, скрипт не срабатывал, когда курсор на кнопке?(Unity2d)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не срабатывала кнопка при нажатии? [interectable = false](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable-interactable.html)...

Answer (score 1):

Есть два метода у `MonoBehaviour` один **[OnMouseEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseEnter.html)** - срабатывает, когда мышка заходит над элемент, **[OnMouseExit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseExit.html)** - когда мышка покидает элемент. Есть ещё **[OnMouseOver](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseOver.html)** - но думаю это ресурсоёмко.

Заводите булеву переменную. При заходе мышки над элементов делаете переменную `true`, при выходе - `false`.  А при клике проверяете, если `true`, то нельзя ничего делать

Answer (score 0):

Компонент Button имеет переменную interactable, которая отвечает за возможность клика на кнопку. interactable = true - кнопка интерактивна, false - нет